# load several fragments at once with jquery .load()

Tags: ajax, dom, jquery, page-fragments

i am loading some fragments with jquery with following code

```
var box = $(this).closest(".product-contain").children(".title:first");
box.load(url + " .maintitle", data);
var box = $(this).closest(".product-contain").children(".detail:first");
box.load(url + " .alldetail", data);
```

(i don't want to load whole .product-contain at once, because part of it is being edited by user at the same moment)

but it does 2 requests to server for same content.

can i somehow do it with one request?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do one [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and load the content where it goes yourself, like this:

```
 var pc = $(this).closest(".product-contain");
 $.get(url, data, function(html) {
   var resp = $(html);
   pc.children(".title:first").html(resp.find(".maintitle"));
   pc.children(".detail:first").html(resp.find(".alldetail"));
 });
```

This may look a little weird, but [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) with a jQuery object is a shortcut for `.empty().append()`.

Comment: Great. To be sure you actually get HTML, set the jQuery.get() dataType to HTML.